# AJAX, no response received

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

```
 if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
$ID = $_GET['delete'];
echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var ajax.open('POST','parser.php', true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(ajax.readyState ==4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            alert(ajax.responseText);
        }
        }
        ajax.send('delete=$ID')
    </script>
    ";
}
```

this is my code, it is supposed to send the id to parser.php

here is parser.php

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    echo $_POST['delete'];
}
```

no response is received from parser.php, can anyone help ?
all answers are much appreciated

Comment: Have you checked the console.Do you have any error.Is the request sending.?

Comment: I'm using wamp and working on localhost. where can I find the console? im not receiving any errors

Comment: Check the browser console and check network in there.You can see the requests there

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: Thats a syntax error.Try to correct it.

Comment: Fixed! I had - var ajax.open('POST','parser.php', true); instead of ajax.open('POST','parser.php', true);

Comment: always when working with webdevelopment use to good browser like firefox  and use the webdeveloperstoolbar and firebug to debug software problems in development fase.